# AgGrid Jest unit test - how to wait for the grid initialization

Tags: angular, jestjs, ag-grid

I'm writing jest unit tests for an Angular component that uses AgGrid. The test fails because cells that use a cellRenderer aren't done initializing.

I tried adding a tick() call and that makes the test pass, but then gives an error about `7 timer(s) still in the queue`.

I also tried `await fixture.whenStable();` and the result was inconsistent, sometimes the test passes and sometimes it fails at the `expect` call since the cell isn't done rendering.

What would be the right way to wait for the cells to be rendered before testing things?

Here's the code when I use tick():

```
describe('MethodListComponent', () => {
  let component: MethodListComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<MethodListComponent>;

  beforeEach(fakeAsync(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [
        testingImports
      ],
      declarations: [MethodListComponent],
      providers: [
        { provide: MethodsService, useValue: mockMethodsService },
        { provide: AuthService, useValue: mockAuthService }
      ],
      schemas: [CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA]
    });

    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(MethodListComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;

    // make sure all columns are rendered for the tests
    component.activeMethodsGrid.gridOptions = {...component.activeMethodsGrid.gridOptions, 'suppressColumnVirtualisation': true};
  }));

  it('test archiving a test method', fakeAsync( async () => {
    // trigger onInit()
    fixture.detectChanges();

    tick(20);

    const archiveButtons = fixture.nativeElement.querySelectorAll(
      'ag-grid-angular .anticon-container'
    );
    expect(archiveButtons.length).toBe(2);
  }));
});
```

And here's the unit test when I use `await fixture.whenStable`:

```
  it('test archiving a test method', async(done) => {
    // trigger onInit()
    fixture.detectChanges();
    
    await fixture.whenStable();
    
    const archiveButtons = fixture.nativeElement.querySelectorAll(
      'ag-grid-angular .anticon-container'
    );
    expect(archiveButtons.length).toBe(2);

    done();
  });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For what it's worth, turns out that the `await fixture.whenStable` code snippet works and the tests pass. The reason it wasn't always passing was that I was making some changes to the test cases while running them.